# Controller returning 404 error even though its returning results

Tags: grails

I have the following mapping in my URLMappings

```
addPurchase:"/addPurchase" {
            controller = "cart"
            action = "addPurchase"
        }
```

I make an AJAX call from my GSP

```
function addPurchase(purchaseJSON, amount) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'addPurchase',
                data: {
                    purchase: purchaseJSON
//                    quantity: amount
                },
                type : "POST",
                complete:function(data) {
                    updateCart();
                    updateOrderSummary(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

My controller code is

```
def addPurchase = {

      def result = cartService.addPurchase(session,params)

      log.debug"Results from addPurchase" + result
      response.status = 200
      return result as JSON

    }
```

Eventhough I see the output in my console, I get an error 404 in my browser. Why is it happening ? My version of grails is @ 1.3.7

Comment: what comes first? the browser error or the console results?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're actually returning a result whereas the required response is a 'text/html' or 'text/json'

So in your controller you should `render` the result instead of `return`ing it; like :

```
def addPurchase = {
    def result = cartService.addPurchase(session,params)
    log.debug"Results from addPurchase" + result
    response.status = 200
    render result as JSON
}
```

Comment: That was it. I guess I didn't pay much attention and thought render and return would be the same.

Comment: The solution above just returns a JSON to be parsed in client side. But better approach would be to make non AJAX redirect to standard /notFound page according to URLMapping.